# Is it possible to add your own currencies or other "countable entities" in GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash

I'm trying to track the income and expenses of an essence that is not listed as any pre-defined `GnuCash` currency (say, bubble gum stickers, number of calories or air temperature). Is it possible to add new entity type and do accounting of that essence?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currencies aren't user editable, but then if you were tracking your investments in bubble gum this probably isn't what you want to do anyway.

What you can do is add what gnucash calls a Security using the tools->security editor dialog.  You can choose one of the pre-defined types (AMEX/NASDAQ/FUND/etc) or just type your own.

Once you've created your own security, just add a new account and select the new type you've added from the drop-down and your new security should appear.  When you transfer cash into or out of these accounts you'll need to set the rate which applies when converting between the two (as with foreign currency transfers).

This is primarly designed for managing investments in stocks and mutual funds, but it will work just as well for bubble gum, calories or whatever other crazy stuff you need double entry level consistency for.  There is also an online quote feature, but last time I checked Yahoo didn't have price data for units of air temperature :).

Comment: What about Bitcoin, etc?

Comment: You can handle Bitcoin manually by just adding a Security called BTC. You would have to update the price conversions manually though. To have the rates converted and priced automatically you would have to get the Yahoo quotes integration to recognise Bitcoin as a ticker.

Answer (score 4):

You can't make currencies, but you can make new funds. I use this feature to track vacation time and point systems that aren't easily converted into dollar amounts. Need to figure out a way to build in default exchange rates, so I don't have to do the math.